# Python: source code has attributes that are unaccessible from outside of it

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i've been wondering around the other day and stumbled across this piece of code from `datetime.datetime`:

```
def timestamp(self):
    "Return POSIX timestamp as float"
    if self._tzinfo is None:
        s = self._mktime()
        return s + self.microsecond / 1e6
    else:
        return (self - _EPOCH).total_seconds()
```

I decided to check what `self._tzinfo` and `self._mktime()` are, so i ran this code in console:

```
>>> datetime(1970, 1, 1)._tzinfo
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '_tzinfo'
>>> datetime(1970, 1, 1)._mktime()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '_mktime'
```

But to my surprise i got `AttributeError` on both occasions. PyCharm says `Cannot find declaration to go to`. Yet, there is a normal declaration of `_mktime()` method right above the `timestamp()` method.

Despite all this, of course, `timestamp()` works totally fine.

```
>>> datetime(1970, 1, 1).timestamp()
-10800.0
```

So why is this happening? Why are these attributes not accessible from outside and why does interpreter react to them so weirdly?

Comment: Where exactly did you find that source code…?

Comment: @deceze well, literally in the source code. `lib > python3.6 > datetime.py`. Got there by crtl+click in PyCharm.

Comment: The `datetime` you see there is not the `datetime` you are using when you call `datetime(1970, 1, 1)`. Scroll to the bottom of the file and you'll see `from _datetime import *`. The star import overrides the `datetime` in the python file with the C implementation of `datetime`.

Comment: @Axe319 Makes sense. But then what is the purpose of all the declarations if they're going to be overrided?

Comment: if you will not have C library then it will still work because it will use Python code. C version may work faster. In some modules C version may have also some restrictions - in `pandas` you can choose `"engine"` and use C version which doesn't have some functions (in some places doesn't work `regex`) or Python version which has all functions

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue7989 Here's the related issue if you care about the rationale.

Comment: There is a convention among programmers (especially those migrated from JAVA to Python) that if a name prefixed with an underscore then it should be treated as a private variable or method, as is said in [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private).

Comment: @MohammadForouhesh There is such a convention, but it doesn't make such attributes unaccessible in python. Python has virtually no encapsulation.

Comment: @go2nirvana encapsulation is not synonymous with access modifiers. Python has encapsulation just fine, except it depends on convention. And without the need for boilerpate getters and setters